# Building websites under Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, web, development-environment

I am about to learn how to build good, well-designed & responsive websites using HTML, JavaScript & PHP. I know that Adobe offers nice tool for developing websites (DreamWeaver if I am not mistaken), but that tool requires monthly subsription.

I am already an owner of Visual Studio Professional 2015, which also allows to create e.g. ASP.NET websites (where under main folder it actually generates html + css code for you).

I would like to know, if it is possible / good practice, to develop already mentioned websites (not ASP.NET) with Visual Studio? I hope that this is a good place where to ask this kind of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. There's a large community of developers creating extensions around it as well.

[Here is an overview](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/modern-web-tooling-vs.aspx) of some of the web tools offered in VS 2015, as well as a [video on Channel 9 from Mads Kristensen](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/Modern-Web-Development-Tools-in-Visual-Studio-2015-with-Mads-Kristensen) on modern web tooling, and much of it is in VS 2015.

Comment: fantastic! Thank you very much